# Issue with equal signs and function parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a function that would allow to repeat this (it prevents the console from opening in windows):

```
 if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        subprocess.call(['myprogram.exe', '-P', arg], 
                       stdout=someFile, startupinfo=startupinfo)
    else:
        subprocess.call(['myprogram.exe', '-P', arg], stdout=someFile)
```

Therefore I defined the following function:

```
def noWinConsole(program):
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        subprocess.call(program, startupinfo=startupinfo)
    else:
        subprocess.call(program)
```

But when I call it like this `noWinConsole(['myprogram.exe', '-P', arg], stdout=someFile)` , I get an error because of `stdout=somefile`:

```
TypeError: noWinConsole() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stdout'
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`noWinConsole` is just a wrapper, and as it stands it's expecting just a single argument, `program`. Thus it freaks out when you give it two arguments (`program` as the first positional argument, and then the keyword argument `stdout` intended for the `subprocess` call).

Luckily, there's a standard idiom for producing a wrapper that passes along any set of arguments to an inner function. It uses the [`*`](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) and [`**`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769475/2069350) notation for argument packing/unpacking.

```
def noWinConsole(*args, **kwargs):
    # Other stuff here as needed
    subprocess.call(*args, **kwargs)
```

What this does is basically this. The `*` operator in the function definition takes all the input positional arguments, and packs them into a tuple called `args`. Then when you call `subprocess`, the `*` operator *unpacks* that tuple, passing in those same arguments in the same order to the next function.

The `**` operator works essentially the same way, except that it catches keyword arguments like `stdout='foo.txt'` and packs all of them into a dictionary like `{'stdout':'foo.txt'}`. This dictionary is then unpacked and converted back into keyword arguments when you use the `**` again in your call to the inner function.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I updated the question with the corrected code, does it seem right to you ?

Comment: @yaka That seems like it will work for your use case, yes. Though it might be clearer later on to use single-star unpacking for the first argument as well. Also, it's generally frowned upon to edit an answer into a question; it murks things up for future visitors. So you should probably remove that. Glad I was able to help!

Comment: @eryksun Yes indeed! I actually considered adding a mention to `partial` here, but I decided against it since it's kind of tangential to the question that the asker really needed answered ("why doesn't Python automatically pack any number of arguments into a single parameter if that's what's in the function signature").

Answer (score 1):

The function `noWinConsole` only expects *one argument*, and when you call it:

```
noWinConsole(['myprogram.exe', '-P', arg], stdout=someFile)
```

you are passing *two arguments*:

- a list
- a keyword argument `stdout = someFile`

**How to fix this?**

You can do this two ways:

- Define your method to get kwargs. Note that you are not using the parameters `stdout`

  ```
  def noWinConsole(program, **kwargs):
  ```
- Call the function just passing one argument:

  ```
  noWinConsole(['myprogram.exe', '-P', arg])
  ```